# Pyspark: Compare Column Values across different dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas, pyspark-schema

we are planning to do the following,
compare two dataframe, based on comparision add values into first dataframe and then groupby to have combined data.

We are using pyspark dataframe and the following are our dataframes.

Dataframe1:

```
| Manager    | Department          |  isHospRelated
| --------   | --------------      | --------------
| Abhinav    | Medical             |  t
| Abhinav    | Surgery             |  t
| Rajesh     | Payments            |  t
| Rajesh     | HR                  |  t
| Sonu       | Onboarding          |  t
| Sonu       | Surgery             |  t
| Sonu       | HR                  |  t
```

Dataframe2:

```
| OrgSupported| OrgNonSupported          |
| --------   | --------------            |
| Medical    | Payment                   |
| Surgery    | Onboarding                |
```

We plan to compare Dataframe1 with Dataframe2 and obtain the following results:

```
| Manager    | Department          | Org Supported | Org NotSupported
| --------   | --------------      | ------------- | ----------------
| Abhinav    | Medical             | Medical       |        
| Abhinav    | Surgery             | Surgery       |
| Rajesh     | Payments            |               | Payments
| Rajesh     | HR                  |               | HR
| Sonu       | Onboarding          |               | Onboarding
| Sonu       | Surgery             | Surgery       | 
| Sonu       | HR                  |               | HR
```

Finally we would like to groupthem as follows:

```
| Manager    | Department         | isHospRelated  | Org Supported  | Org NotSupported
| --------   | --------------     | ------------   | -------------  | ----------------
| Abhinav    | Medical,Surgery    | t              | Medical,Surgery|        
| Rajesh     | Payments, HR       | t              |                | Payments, HR
| Sonu     | Onboarding,Surgery,HR| t              |  Surgery       | Onboarding, HR
```

We are using pyspark in our code, any suggestions how do we do these kind of comparison in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one solution, i am joining df2 two times first to get NonSupported then to get supported. When its done its easy to group by manager and collect_lists of values

You can try something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = [
    {"Manager": "Abhinav", "Department": "Medical", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Abhinav", "Department": "Surgery", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Rajesh", "Department": "Payments", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Rajesh", "Department": "Hr", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Sonu", "Department": "Onboarding", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Sonu", "Department": "Surgery", "isHospRelated": "t"},
]

df2 = [
    {"OrgSupported": "Medical", "OrgNonSupported": "Payments"},
    {"OrgSupported": "Surgery", "OrgNonSupported": "Onboarding"},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)

dfWithNonSupported = df.join(
    df2.drop("OrgNonSupported"), df.Department == df2.OrgSupported, "left"
)
dfWithSupportedAndNonSupported = dfWithNonSupported.join(
    df2.drop("OrgSupported"),
    dfWithNonSupported.Department == df2.OrgNonSupported,
    "left",
)

finalDf = dfWithSupportedAndNonSupported.withColumn(
    "OrgNonSupported",
    F.when(
        (F.col("OrgSupported").isNull()) & (F.col("OrgSupported").isNull()),
        F.col("Department"),
    ).otherwise(F.col("OrgNonSupported")),
)

finalDf.groupBy("Manager").agg(
    F.collect_list("Department").alias("Department"),
    F.collect_list("OrgSupported").alias("OrgSupported"),
    F.collect_list("OrgNonSupported").alias("OrgNonSupported"),
    F.first("isHospRelated").alias("isHospRelated"),
).show()
```

output:

```
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
|Manager|          Department|      OrgSupported|OrgNonSupported|isHospRelated|
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
|Abhinav|  [Medical, Surgery]|[Medical, Surgery]|             []|            t|
| Rajesh|      [Payments, Hr]|                []| [Payments, Hr]|            t|
|   Sonu|[Onboarding, Surg...|         [Surgery]|   [Onboarding]|            t|
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This solution is working great, I need a small help on top of this, what if the first dataframe, 

df = [
    {"Manager": "Abhinav", "Department": "Medical", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Abhinav", "Department": "Surgery", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Rajesh", "Department": "Payments", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Sonu", "Department": "Onboarding", "isHospRelated": "t"},
    {"Manager": "Sonu", "Department": "Surgery", "isHospRelated": "t"},
]

Has a constant column into it, 
and we want to retain that column while getting final df?

Comment: You have few options here. You can include this column in groupBy and then just select it together with other columns. If you are sure that there is only one value and you dont want to change group by you can use some agg function to get this value, for example function "first". I updated my answer

Comment: @ M_S need your help, I got a case where some departments are not present in second dataframe, example HR in above question under manager Rajesh, how do we handle that to be present in OrgNonSupported.

Anything that is absent in dataframe2 we put it in OrgNonSupported.

updated the question, please guide.

Comment: @frpfarhan what have you tried so far? You can add this logic with when/otherwise before grouping, check my answer

Comment: thanks for your response, quick question why do we check two Null on same column : ```(F.col("OrgSupported").isNull()) & (F.col("OrgSupported").isNull())```

Comment: To do not copy department to NonSupported when OrgSupported is filled. If you think that it may be different just change it :) You know the pattern now